# Array as parameter

Tags: c++

I was wondering which one of these is the best when I pass an array as parameter?

```
void function(int arr[]) {...};
```

or

```
void function(int* arr) {...};
```

Could you tell me your reason? and which book you might refer to? Thanks!

Comment: When you pass an array to function it decays as a pointer to the first element of the array. So both are identical.

Comment: Out of these? `void function(std::string const& str) {...};` is best.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4810672/78845

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this question is tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), I would use neither. If you *must* use this, both are equivalent.

But since you use C++, a better approach is to use a `std::vector` for such tasks

```
void function(std::vector<int> &arr) {...}
```

or, if you don't modify the array/vector

```
void function(const std::vector<int> &arr) {...}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to pass any array (including dynamically allocated), they are equivalent.

Should your function require an actual fixed-size array, you could do this:

```
template <size_t N>
void function(char (&str)[N]) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

They are semantically identical.

#1 is slightly better (in my opinion) because it makes it explicit that you are passing an array.

Comment: They are _syntactically_ different.  They are _semantically_ equivalent.

Comment: And I must confess, I prefer #2, but not because it makes it explicit you're passing an array; I prefer it because it makes it explicit you're passing an **address** =P

Answer (score 1):

You ask which to choose of

```
void function(int arr[]) {...};
```

and

```
void function(int* arr) {...};
```

The latter allows you to declare the pointer itself as `const`, while the former only allows you to declare the items as `const`. However, to the reader `[]` indicates an array as opposed to possibly a pointer to a single object. Personally I think the constraint offered by `const` is more practically useful than the indication of array'ness offered by `[]`.

For higher level code, use `std::vector` or `std::array`, whichever is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to pass an array as a parameter is actually:

`void function(type_t* array, int amountOfElts, int arrayAllocatedElts);`

For some cases (like when passing strings) you can often skip these two parameters. But they may be useful either way, for example when doing some operations on the string, or they may save you a strlen call or two.

Using the [] option in function arguments is in my opinion confusing and should be avoided. But I don't think it's a convention.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the layer of abstraction you want to provide, you should chose between Olaf's approach or something STL uses to the great level:

```
template <class Iter>
void function(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    // for example, to get size:
    std::size_t size = std::distance(first, last);
    // for example, to iterate:
    for ( Iter it = first; it != last; ++it )
    {
        // *it to get the value, like:
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
}
```

That way, you can use the function not only for arrays, but for various STL types: vectors, lists, queues, stacks and so.

```
int tab[4] = {1,2,3,4};
function(tab, tab+4);

std::vector<int> vec;
// fill vector with something
function(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```